# On what factors does the true reaction Stoichiometry depend when there are multiple valid options?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stoichiometry

Consider the following unbalanced reaction:

$$\ce{XeF4 + H2O -> Xe + XeO2 + HF + O2}$$

There are six variables to be solved, but only four equations linking them. I solved the set of equations using Gauss elimination and arbitrarily set the stoichiometric coefficient of $\ce{XeF4}$ as $3$:

$$\ce{3XeF4 + 6H2O -> $(4k)$Xe + $(3-4k)$XeO2 + 12HF + $(4k)$O2}$$

where $k$ is the free variable, the parameter, with $0<k<\frac 34$ (since coefficients must be positive).

Clearly, for different values of $k$, it gives radically different yet balanced equations. The very yields are different for fixed amount of $\ce{XeF4}$ and $\ce{H2O}$. This issue has been noted in a [previous question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58069/can-a-chemical-reaction-have-two-balanced-equations).

My textbook, however, gives the balanced equation:

$$\ce{6XeF4 + 12H2O -> 4Xe + 2XeO2 + 24HF + 4O2}$$

clearly setting $k=\frac 12$. The linked question above does not offer any explanation for why a particular value of $k$ should be favoured. So, my exact question is: Why set $k=\frac 12$? Why was $\frac 12$ preferred over any other value for $k$:

- Is it determined by experimentally measuring the stoichiometry?
- Is there a theoretical explanation for it?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37684/write-the-chemical-equation-of-this-reaction

Comment: chemical equations are not unlike math equations, multiplying each side by same number will give a valid equation. Similarly, addition of two (or more) equations side-wise with subsequent simplification gives a valid equation. However, if the equation depicts an actual chemical process is another matter, a well-balanced equation may be irrelevant for this reason.

Comment: @Mithoron In the answer to that question, they just say that the balanced equations are _different_. I want to know which is correct and why? Which factors determine that? And it is not a duplicate because he mentions just 2 possibilities and I found all the solutions.

Comment: I would change the title of your question to better reflect the change you made. Something along the lines of "How to determine true reaction stoichiometry among multiple valid options".

Comment: There is a meta discussion on the closure of this question: [Possible overreach on marked duplicate](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3710/possible-overreach-on-marked-duplicate)

Comment: While I never quite figured this paper out and it doesn't give a concrete example of carrying this process out, I think this [paper](http://www.public.asu.edu/~baluk/reprints/469.pdf) addresses your  question. For just finding these solutions, check out this [paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1110/1110.4321.pdf) or summaries by [Fred Senese](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24245/are-matrices-a-good-way-to-do-stoichiometry?rq=1) or [myself](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68924/what-is-the-simplest-approach-to-balance-a-complex-reaction-equation/70540#70540)

Comment: Recently found another great resource on this topic that I haven't gotten a chance to read all the way through. Section 7 seems to address your concerns: http://www.chemical-stoichiometry.net/CRS_tut.pdf